# Trying to add Parallax scrolling to a website that is already designed. It isn't working for some reason. Can someone assist?

Tags: css, html, parallax

I'm trying to add Parallax Scrolling to a website that is already designed. It isn't working for some reason. Can someone assist? The tutorial that I was using is this one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D75WTf_Y738&list=PLG77V5Yi8Ih_yRxLPALtog4AtVyHEuRwf&index=10

This is the script that I wrote:

```
 <script>
        function parallax(){
            var intro_section = document.getElementById ('intro_section');
            intro_section.style.top = -(window.pageYOffest / 10)+'px';
        }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
    </script>
```

This is the HTML section that I am trying to add the effect to.

```
 <div id="intro_section" class="clearfix">
        <div id="Intro_section_container" class="clearfix">
            <p id="We_Know_Why_You’re_Here" class="animated fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".2s">
            We Know Why Your Here
            </p>
            <p id="text" class="animated fadeInUp" data-wow-duration=".2s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
            <span id="textspan2">The computer network at the heart of your small business is glitchy, loses data, refuses to sync with your mobile devices, or runs slower than a turtle with a limp. Sound about right&#x3f;</span><br />
            </p>
            <p id="text1" class="animated fadeInUp" data-wow-duration=".5s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
            HOW DID WE KNOW&#x3f;
            </p>
            <p id="text2" class="animated fadeInUp" data-wow-duration=".5s" data-wow-delay=".4s">
            <span id="textspan3">CloudPoint Technology&#x27;s Managed IT Services clients USED to have those same problems too.&nbsp;</span><br />
            </p>
            <div id="find_out_button" class="clearfix wow fadeIn">
                <p id="Find_out_more_about_us">
                Learn More About Us
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS related to this section.

```
 #intro_section {
   float: none;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
clear: none;
width: 100%;
background: url("img/abstrack_bg.jpg");
background-position: 5% 0%;
background-repeat: no-repeat 0px 50px;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom: 8%;
margin-right: auto;
padding-top: 8%;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
}

#Intro_section_container {
float: none;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
clear: none;
width: 85%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
min-height: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
}

#We_Know_Why_You’re_Here {
float: none;
font-size: 746.7%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 100%;
color: rgb(160, 176, 187);
font-style: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Dagny Pro';
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 101;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
clear: none;
min-height: 0px;
text-shadow: rgba(100, 124, 140, 0.709804) 0px 3px 3px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

}

I can put up a live feed of the dev website if needed.

I appreciate any help that I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what “It isn't working” means. Does it show an error? It doesn't do what you think it should? What does it do? What do you think it should do?

Comment: Sorry, Just nothing is happening. It just seems like a fixed background still.

Comment: http://cyndeeadkinsdesign.com/client_div/page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is typo at

```
    intro_section.style.top = -(window.pageYOffest / 10)+'px';
```

it should be

```
    intro_section.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 10)+'px';
```

also you should add

```
position:fixed;
```

to css of intro_section

here I made a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qbfdwom5/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tanaydin. The demo looks like it added the script to the text making it scroll slow, not the image for the background.Does that make sense?

Comment: Tanaydin, did you give up one me? :( I linked a div site above for you. It's just the home page with no working links.